# Analytic calculation of Jacobian derivative(second order kinematic differentials)

Tags: c++, robotics

I need to calculate the time derivative of the Jacobian. I want to do it analytical, I cannot calculate it numerical. I calculate `J_i` with the scheme in respect of the Denavit-Hartenberg Parameters
`J_i = [z_(i-1) 0]^T` if it is an linear-axis etc.

I know need a simple method to come from this `J` to `dJ/dt`. Has anyone any experience with that problem? There is a formula with derivates `J_i`, but in this formula I do not know what the parameters define, but maybe someone knows what they are:

linear axis:

```
J_i = [(w_(i-1) x z_(i-1))  0]^T
rotation axis:
J_i = [(w_(i-1) x z_(i-1)) x r_(i-1) + z_(i-1) x ( v_(i,n9 + w_(i-1) x r_(i-1))  (w_(i-1) x z_(i-1))]^T
```

Here `r_i-1` is the distance to the TCP. I don t know what `w_i-1` and `v_i,n` is. Any help or any different suggestion?

Thank you guys

Comment: It sounds like a question more suitable for http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you I will ask there too:)